# jQuery: Is it possible to select elements with only one class from among elements with, potentially, up to 3 classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

For example, say I have the following:

```
<span class="a b c">Has class a, b, and c</span>  
<span class="a">Has class a</span>  
<span class="b c">Has class b and c</span> 
<span class="a c">Has class a and c</span> 
<span class="a c">Has class a and c</span> 
<span class="a">Has class a</span>
```

Now, suppose I want to select all elements that have **only** class a.
Meaning only the second and last `span`s would get selected.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 39):

```
$('.a').not('.b, .c')
```

This will select all elements with class `a` that do not have `b` or `c`. However, they could still have class `d`, `e`, etc. Use Phil's answer if you really only want elements with no class other than `a`.

Comment: Upvoting because allowing unrelated classes is probably preferable in a lot of cases, and the resulting code is cleaner. While this is less "future proof", you probably won't actually want the kind of future-proof that my answer gives (which matches the exact question in the OP).

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).not is not a function`

Answer (score 9):

*(See below for why you might not want to do exactly what's asked in the question)*

You could use the `[class="a"]` "attribute equals selector", though it is brittle:

```
$('span[class="a"]').hide();
```

The problem is that if you have any whitespace in your class attribute then it will break.  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c7DP7/

You can fix this by doing a basic query on those items using a normal class selector, then further filter them while checking only `a` is set (and trimming whitespace in that second filter).  See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uD48E/1/

```
$('.a')
    .filter(function(index){
        return $(this).attr("class").trim() == "a";
    })
    .hide();
```

---

The question looks like it is trying to make more "future proof" code, but that specific approach is more brittle. Rejecting all classes that aren't related to the current class you're filtering for can break things for reasons not related to class `a` (like an unrelated class `d` or `e` that gets added later). This is important if the HTML you're applying your jQuery to might be changed in the future.

A better way to do this is to filter out only the classes that impact the meaning of class `a`. Allowing for that sort of flexibility is what actually makes your code more future-proof. See [maxedison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512136/232593) for the best way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose if you wanted to do this you could simply do:

```
var spans = $("span[class='a']");
```

Comment: Brief note to the OP: you don't have to include the word `span` in the selector like Phil has here. If there are divs or imgs that might have the desired class and you'd like to select those to, `$("[class='a']")` will do it.

Comment: The problem with this is if the attribute contains any whitespace, it will break.  Class selectors don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is removing that classes and then checking to see if any classes remain. If no, execute the function:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwp1axqs/2/)

```
$('.a').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.removeClass('a').attr('class').length) {
       //Execute function here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

jQuery:

```
$('[class="a"]');
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class='a']");
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.