# How to select the paragraph with only specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, paragraph

Let say I have my HTML code look like this:

```
<p class="p">Paragraph</p>
<p class="p p2">Paragraph 2</p>
<p class="p p3">Paragraph 3</p>
```

If I use: `$('.p').css('color','red')`, this will apply red color to all paragraphs.

How can I apply the style to paragraph that only has class `p` which is first paragraph in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Is it possible to select elements with only one class from among elements with, potentially, up to 3 classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512111/jquery-is-it-possible-to-select-elements-with-only-one-class-from-among-element)

Comment: Why are you counting your `p`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.p[class="p"]').css('color', 'red');
```

or:

```
$("p[class='p']").css('color', 'red');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHNBC/)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use attribute selector:

```
$('p[class="p"]').css('color','red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/umxGh/

Or:

```
$('p').filter(function(){
   return this.className === 'p';
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('p[class="p"]').css('color','red')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[class=p]').css('color','red');
```