# Get value OR Text of div according to SINGLE CSS Only

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have two divs as shown below :

```
<div class="a b">Hello</div>  // div with two classes

<div class="a"> Hii </div>  // div with single class.
```

Both divs have a common class "a". I want to get value OR text of div with class "a" only i.e Second div. It should not fetch the value of first div.

P.S : There is no id for both the divs SO Don't say to use different IDs. I want it using class only.

Comment: you can use the Jquery selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.a').not('.b').text()
```

Use the `.not` selector to filter out undesidered elements: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

---

Alternatively, to really make sure you only selects divs with class `a`

```
$('div[class="a"]')
```

For further reference: [jQuery: Is it possible to select elements with only one class from among elements with, potentially, up to 3 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512111/jquery-is-it-possible-to-select-elements-with-only-one-class-from-among-element)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you should use to check weather it has only class `a` or any other class too..

```
 $('.a').each(function(){
    var classList = $(this).attr("class");
    classList = classList.trim().split(" ");
    if(classList.length ==1){
         //do your stuff
    }
 });
```

or you can use

```
 $('.a').each(function(){
    var classList = $(this).attr("class");
    classList = classList.trim();
    if(classList === "a"){
         //do your stuff
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah but what if you don't know which other class may be included or what type of element we use?

(assuming we use jQuery)

```
$('.a').each(function(i, ele){

    if($(ele).attr('class')==='a'){
        // get value or text here
    }
});
```

This is faster though

```
$('[class="a"]').each(/* get our values with a function in here */)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple we can take only if we want to select only one class we can use like following
`$('div[class="a"]')` this will fetch the div have only class `a`

```
<div class="a b">Hello</div>  // div with two classes

<div class="a"> Hii </div>  // div with single class.
```

### script

```
console.log($('div[class="a"]').html());
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ccrrC/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that styling with Just Pure CSS(CSS3),

```
 div:not(.b){color:red;}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/WndAf/**

jQuery Solution, to get the Div text

```
   $(function() {
  console.log($("div:not(.b)").text());
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/WndAf/5/**

Comment: OP is asking for piece of jquery code that returns the TEXT inside the div.

Comment: This returns the text of **any** div that does not have class `b`, presumably the two divs in the OP are not the only divs in the document. Hence the one with class `a` is likely not the only one without class `b`.