# How to select elements that have a specific class, and then select elements that have that class and another

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following radio buttons:

```
// these should be included in sauce_flavor
<input type="radio" value="S." onclick="countPBClicks('S')" name="sauce.left" class="pb-radio-sauce default-sauce">
<input type="radio" value="S.C" onclick="countPBClicks('SF')" name="sauce.left" class="pb-radio-sauce make-table">

// this should be included in sauce
<input type="radio" value="S.reg_sauce" onclick="countPBClicks('S')" name="sauce.left" class="pb-radio-sauce ">
```

I have a switch that needs to have two separate flows for items that have only the `pb-radio-sauce' class and items that have both the`pb-radio-sauce`class and either`default-sauce`or 'make-table`.

```
case 'sauce':
    retval = {};
    jQuery('.pb-radio-sauce:checked').each(function() {

            var elem = jQuery(this);
            retval[elem.val()] = String(elem.attr('name')).split('.')[1];
            });
    break;
case 'sauce_flavor':
    retval = {};
    jQuery('.pb-radio-sauce make-table:checked').each(function() {

            var elem = jQuery(this);
            retval[elem.val()] = String(elem.attr('name')).split('.')[1];
            });
    break;
```

The problem is, I can't seem to come up with the correct selectors to split them out this way. `('.pb-radio-sauce:checked')` finds all results, including the ones with the secondary class and then hits the break, so it never gets to the sauce_flavor option. And I'm not sure how to include two possible secondary classes in the sauce_flavor instance while still including the checked attribute.

I have a stripped-down [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/V4qmd/1/) (without the switch; just defined functions) that shows what's going on. It doesn't matter what order I define the functions; all checked items still get caught by the `pb-radio-sauce` selector.

Comment: What is with String(), that is not needed. Do you want to have `:not(.otherClass)`?

Comment: This is really old code I inherited and have to add new functionality to. I left the `String()` in because the codebase is a nightmare and I'd rather not start messing with the bits that are currently working. As for `:not`, no - for that to work, you have to be specific about which classes you DON'T want. There are many other classes that can be combined with `pb-radio-sauce`, and I can't include all of them in a `:not`. I need a way to specify positively which classes to find, not negatively which classes not to find.

Comment: So you want an OR? Find X or Y? `$("[type=radio]:checked").filter(".x, .y")...`

Comment: I need two separate finds. I need to find all checked radio buttons that have ONLY the `pb-radio-sauce` class and do one thing with those, then I need to find all the checked radio buttons that have BOTH the `pb-radio-sauce` class AND EITHER `default-sauce` OR `make-table` to do something entirely different with those.

Comment: check out this page on additional ways to isolate your sauce http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512111/jquery-is-it-possible-to-select-elements-with-only-one-class-from-among-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just grab a collection of all checked radio buttons, then split them out using a conditional for your criteria.

[Here is a modified version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4qmd/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $( '.pb-radio-sauce:checked' ).each( function() {
    if( $(this).hasClass( 'default-sauce' ) || $(this).hasClass( 'make-table' ) ) {
         console.log( "sauce flavor" );
         console.log($(this));
    } else {
        console.log( "just sauce" );
        console.log($(this));
    }


} );
})
```

**Edit**:
Ah ok, what you need is http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ 
[Here is a different modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4qmd/15/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '.pb-radio-sauce:checked' ).each( function() {
        if( $(this).hasClass( 'default-sauce' ) || $(this).hasClass( 'make-table' ) ) {
             console.log( "sauce flavor" );
             console.log($(this));
        }
    } );

    $( 'input[class="pb-radio-sauce"]:checked' ).each( function() {
             console.log( "just sauce" );
             console.log($(this));

    } );
})
```

The [class="pb-radio-sauce"] selector will only select items with just "pb-radio-sauce" as a class.

Comment: As I said in a comment to the original post, there are many other classes that can be combined with `pb-radio-sauce`, and using an `if-else` is going to blow up because the `else` is going to find everything that contains any of those other classes, which I don't want. I need this to be very specific - find radios that have ONLY `pb-radio-sauce` AND EITHER `default-sauce` OR `make-table` - your solution would allow the `else` to find radios that have `pb-radio-sauce restricted-sauce`, for example.

Comment: your latest edit might not work due to the whitespace in her pb-radio-sauce. This is another option .not('.alltheothersauces, .andanothersauce')